# jQuery Animate not working on mouse move

Tags: jquery, animation

i'm working on an animated image gallery which you can see in the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/brodiecapel16/3xkbmo8p/) with jQuery, it has a few features:

1. Hover over a category to reveal the images in that category
2. Click an image to change load it in the full size display
3. when the mouse is on the right hand or left had side of the screen, the list of images displaying scrolls to the left or right accordingly.

steps one and two work fine, but item number 3 the animations are not working, this is my first time working with animations in jQuery and i have been pulling my hair out.... can anyone see where I am goin wrong?

this is my code for detecting the mouse position (works fine) and then animating it accordingly (doesn't work)

```
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {  
    var mX = e.pageX;
    var width = $(window).width();
    var buffer = parseInt(width) / 3;
    var rightBuf = width - buffer;
    var leftBuf = rightBuf - buffer;
    if(mX > rightBuf){
        $('.menu-sub').animate({ "left": "-50px" }, "slow" );
    }else if(mX < leftBuf){
        $('.menu-sub').animate({ "left": "50px" }, "slow" );          
    }else{

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move your image list you can use

```
$('.menu-sub ul').animate({ "margin-left": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
```

But you should not use `.mousemove()` because it is called every time the mouse moves one pixel. You could use hidden divs and bind `hover` as you have done for the headings. In your `mouseover` event you could execute something like

```
hovering = true;
while (hovering) {
// animate
}
```

And set `hovering` to false in your `mouseout` event.

I also updated your fiddle to at least wait a second before scrolling again: http://jsfiddle.net/3xkbmo8p/16/

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to animate a div like you want. The left will only affect things that are in position:absolute.

There 2 solutions, wrap it in a position:relative div or use the margin to animate the div.

```
$('.menu-sub').animate({ "margin-left": "-50px" }, "slow" );
```

Comment: it works! but its glitchy as hell and it only seems to run if there are no sections that are currently .slideDown() (which kinda defeats the point) any idea why?